# If compiler can perform implicit narrowing conversion on an integer literal, then it should also 

Tags: c#, .net

If compiler is able to implicitly convert integer literal into byte type and assign the result to b ( b = 100; ), why can’t it also implicitly assign the result of an expression a+100 ( result is of type integer ) to b?

```
        byte a = 10;
        byte b = a; //ok
        b = 100; //ok
        b = a + 100;//error - explicit cast needed
        b = (byte)(a + 100); // ok
```

thanx

Comment: Exactly what language and compiler are you talking about? Java?

Comment: @Stephen, the question is tagged C#, but Java treats it the same way.

Comment: Good point, sorry, I missed the tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about static type safety - whether, at compile time, we can safety know the type of an expression. With a literal, the compiler can correctly tell that if it can be converted to a byte. In `byte a = 20`, 20 is convertible, so it all goes through fine. `byte a = 257` won't work (257 can't be converted).

In the case `byte b = a`, then we already know a is a byte, so type safety is assured. `b = 100` is again fine (it's statically known that 100 is convertible).

In `b = a + 100`, it is *not* statically known if `a + 100` is a byte. `a` could contain 200, so `a + 100` is not representable as a byte. Hence the compiler forces you to tell it "Yes, `a + 100` is always a byte" via a cast, by appealing to your higher level programmer knowledge.

Some types of more advanced type systems don't suffer from this problem, but come with their own problems that most programmers won't like.

Comment: I'm curious - do you have a pointer to such a type system / language and the problems that accompany it?

Comment: BTW - Shouldn't compiler throw an error with statements like b += 100;  since there is a potential for overflowing?

Comment: @AspOnMyNet: There is such a potential, yes. The b+=x operator in this example is defined as having the semantics of "b = (byte)((int)b + (int)x)" by the specification. If you do this in a "checked" context then you'll get an overflow error at runtime, but we allow it at compile time because this is a common idiom.

Comment: calmh - Have a Google for "Dependent types" for part of the general theory.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler allows you to implicitly convert an integer literal into a byte, since it can, at compile time, check the value of the literal to make sure that it's a byte, and treat it as a byte literal.

You can see this if you try the following:

```
byte a = 10; // Works, since 10 is valid as byte
byte b = 239832; // Gives error!
```

The error you get if you put an arbitrary int is:

> Error 1   Constant value '239832' cannot be converted to a 'byte'

When you're adding a literal to a byte:

```
b = a + 100
```

There's the potential for overflowing, so it's not implicitly allowed.  You need to tell the compiler that you explicitly want this to happen, via a cast.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the assigning version of the operator (`+=`) then it will perform the narrowing conversion on the result without reporting an error:

```
byte a = 10;
byte b = a; //ok
b = 100; //ok

b = a;
b += 100;//ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Because treating literals specially is easy and useful; having the compiler distinguish all expressions consisting of compile-time constants and treat them specially would be far more work and far less useful.